# Nextflow channel only processing first tuple in channel

Tags: nextflow

i'm loading single end files into an align process in nextflow. I view the channel and it shows both files (there are only two files in my exmple):

```
Channel.fromFilePairs(params.fastqfiles,size: 1,checkIfExists: true ).set{file_list_ch}
file_list_ch.view()
```

```
[193fin, [193fin.fastq.gz]]

[829fin, [829fin.fastq.gz]]
```

But then when run a process with this channel, it only uses the first one and

```
[1a/11f063] process > INDEX (1) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[e7/89e2be] process > ALIGN (1) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
```

part of the process is as follows:

```
ALIGN(index_ch,file_list_ch)
```

```
process ALIGN{

     
    


    input:
        path index, stageAs: "bowtie_index/*"
        tuple val(sample_id), path(reads)
```

I have the example of the nf-core workshop and it's identical except it is single ended, but it still just runs one process.

how can i make it run all the processes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issues like this almost always involve the use of [multiple input channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-multiple-input-channels):

> When two or more channels are declared as process inputs, the process
> waits until there is a complete input configuration, i.e. until it
> receives a value from each input channel. When this condition is
> satisfied, the process consumes a value from each channel and launches
> a new task, repeating this logic until one or more channels are empty.

You didn't show how *index_ch* was created, but I suspect it is actually a [queue channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel). What you want instead is a [value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel):

> A different semantic is applied when using a [value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#channel-type-value). This kind
> of channel is created by the [Channel.value](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#channel-value) factory method or
> implicitly when a process is invoked with an argument that is not a
> channel. By definition, a value channel is bound to a single value and
> it can be read an unlimited number of times without consuming its
> content. Therefore, when mixing a value channel with one or more
> (queue) channels, it does not affect the process termination because
> the underlying value is applied repeatedly.

Comment: Actualy the issue was something else completely which just highlights how bad the documentation for nextflow is.

Comment: @raygozag Was it some configuration issue? Please consider adding an answer and marking it as accepted. That way, future readers will know what worked.